# Prolog recursive calls

Tags: prolog

So, I have a prolog predicate that for example is something like this:

```
getSomething([Head|Tail],List,MaxV,MaxK,BestThing) :-
           %I call other functions that work just fine
           makeaverage(List,Med),
           compare(Med,MaxV,Comp),
           (Comp < MaxK, 
           getSomething(Tail,List,MaxV,Comp,Head);
           getSomething(Tail,List,MaxV,MaxS,BestThing)),
           write(BestThing).
```

And the problem is that Best thing is actually _G267 and write returns :

Thing1
Thing2
Thing3
_G267

and I really need Thing1 but the when the predicate returns recursively screws everything up... so... some help would be great :).

I fixed it :

```
    getSomething([Head],List,MaxV,MaxK,BestThing) :-
           makeaverage(List,Med),
           compare(Med,MaxV,Comp),
           MaxK = Comp,
           BestTHing = Head .
    getSomething([Head|Tail],List,MaxV,MaxK,BestThing) :-
           getSomething(Tail,List,MaxV,Comp1,Head1),
           makeaverage(List,Med),
           compare(Med,MaxV,Comp),
           (Comp < MaxK
           ->
           MaxK = Comp,
           BestThing = Head;
           MaxK = Comp,
           BestThing = Head1).
```

Or something like that the idea is that you go recursively with not initalized variables and you initialize them at the end of the last recursive call in the one element list part...

Comment: You should show all clauses for your predicate. It's impossible to tell what's wrong.

Comment: When you say function you mean predicate

Comment: If you have fixed it, what is the actual question?

Comment: At the end of the recursion getSomething([Head],List,MaxV,MaxK,BestThing) ... BestTHing = Head  inititalize nothing neither Head, neither BestThing

Comment: `BestTHing` should be `BestThing`

Answer (score 0):

Just copying my previous comment as an answer:

`BestTHing` should be `BestThing` in the first clause for `getSomething`,

which will unify the fouth argument of `getSomething` with the single element of its first argument.